# Java - any ways to create standalone GUI apps for PC/Mac?

Tags: java, installation, package

I'm interested are there any ways to create completely standalone desktop apps on JAVA? I mean to pack JAVA runtimes in distribution package, build apps for MAC/PC running *.jar files and get completely cross-platform software not depending on JAVA installed on target machine?

Comment: Considering the Java Runtime Environment _is_ dependant on which target environment it's installed on, this will be difficult without creating a hugely bloated install package, I think. =)

Comment: hmm... this is an interesting question, but I haven't yet heard of platform-independent JRE

Comment: Have a look at [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Comment: @cmmi Eclipse has different install pckgs for each platofrm, no?

Comment: Actually I dont use Eclipse, but I've installed it a few days ago - the installer itself doesn't seem to be compiled on Java... But I'm not sure

Comment: Eclipse installer??? There is none? Just unpack and start.

Comment: @OP This is plainly not possible. You would need at least one executable wich would start on any platform you support to start setup/configuration. You may though use different wrappers for the specific OS to simplify installation of runtimes

Comment: OMG, you are right! I had a memory failure. Certainly, it was a simple archive with *.app file. I thought about another app

Comment: Daniel Leschkowski, yeah, I know. I'm ready to write a simple wrapper for every OS, but just a wapper, the app itself should be written o JAVA. The problem is how to make this java-app work with JAVA-runtime, placed in the target directory without previous JRM install.

Comment: Java is not an acronym, no need to write it with all-caps "JAVA".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is plainly not possible. You would need at least one executable wich would start on any platform you support to start setup/configuration. You may though use different wrappers for the specific OS to simplify installation of runtimes

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm ready to write a simple wrapper for every OS, but just a wapper, the app itself should be written o JAVA. The problem is how to make this java-app work with JAVA-runtime, placed in the target directory without previous JRM install.

Comment: and which runtime should I place to the setup bundle, what setups should perform my wrapper before launching java-file etc.

Comment: As far as i am aware of you only need to bundle the jre in the Programroot so it looks like {Progroot}/jre/bin, no setup needed if you just copy a working installation of that platform like explained. If you want to use wrappers to install a jre onto the users System if needed, then i would recommend not to write your own wrapper, but use solid wrappers like launch4j, they can even download the recommended jre - if not available already - and prompt the user for installation.

Comment: The preferred method for me -is a maximum standalone app, without suggesting of install/downloading smth additionally. The size of a final package doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I've noticed that uıƃʎɹuɯ lǝıuɐp wrote about «Native Gui elements are used». I'm not too familiar with JAVA at this moment - could you tell me, are there any option for the method you suggested for creating native GUI?

Comment: Just take a look @ http://eclipse.org/swt/  
This is the project-page of SWT, the Standard Widget Toolkit. It is used by Eclipse (Though wrapped by JFace) to use the native widgets to create the Gui. Just add the os-specific lib to your Buildpath and you are on the go. You find various tutorials on the page too. Have fun =)

Comment: Man, i was a bit confused at the time of writing as bundling itself wont work..... Make a wrapper wich calls the JRE bundled like: `@ECHO OFF jre\bin\java.exe -jar installer.jar` in a for Win and as a shellscript for mac `#!/bin/sh ./jre/bin/java -jar installer.jar` ... If you want to call it from an executable in C, you may just use `system()` That will work